# Why isn't the Heroku CLI passing my credentials properly?

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I'm using the Heroku toolbelt v3.27.1 (latest as of this writing) on Windows and unable to login when running `heroku login`.

The error I'm seeing by setting `EXCON_DEBUG=true` is:

```
{\"id\":\"unauthorized\",\"error\":\"There were no credentials in your Authorization` header. Try `Authorization: Bearer <OAuth access token>` or `Authorization: Basic <base64-encoded email + \\\":\\\" + password>`.\"}
```

Strange thing is that I don't receive the same error when I purposely input the wrong password. I have re-installed and the same error occurs.

How can I fix this? I'm unable to find any information with regards to this error.

Comment: a couple things to help diagnose, you could try to run it with HEROKU_DEBUG=true—though I'm not sure how helpful that will be. Another idea is that you could try Fiddler to see what the actual header being passed is.

Comment: @JeffDickey - Enabling `HEROKU_DEBUG` did help me solve my problem. I was able to determine from the logs that the SSL certificate was rejected. If you'd like you can post this as an answer and I'll gladly accept. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try to run it with HEROKU_DEBUG=true and see some debug info about the requests